# elasticlunr.js not showing results for search query

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I used [elasticlunr.js](http://elasticlunr.com/) search engine.

I edited their example source code

```
$('input').bind("enterKey", function (e) {

    var value_test = $("#inputSuccess1").val();

    if ($(this).val() < 2) return
    var config = $('#configuration').val();
    config.trim();
    var json_config = null;
    if (config != '') {
        json_config = new elasticlunr.Configuration(config, idx.getFields()).get();
    }

    var query = value_test;
    var results = null;

    console.log(query);

    if (json_config == null) {
        results = idx.search(query).map(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return questions.filter(function (q) {
                console.log(q);
                return q.page_id === parseInt(result.ref, 10)
            })[0]
        })
    } else {
        results = idx.search(query, json_config).map(function (result) {
            return questions.filter(function (q) {
                return q.page_id === parseInt(result.ref, 10)
            })[0]
        })
    }
    renderQuestionList(results);
    console.log(results);
});
```

All stored search results are displayed on load but when I enter a search query, it returns the supposed un-edited search results. Though the search result array is populated (for e.g.) by 2 items , it is still undefined. I tried to put my own result (just 1) on the example_index.json and tried to input tags relevant to it. It still doesn't show.

HTML CODE

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <main class="main" role="main" style="margin-top: 30px">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <header style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">
                    <h1>Elasticlunr<span>.js</span></h1>
                    <h2>Lightweight full-text search engine in Javascript for browser search and offline search.</h2>
                </header>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span><strong><i>Search Configuration:</i></strong></span>
                    <textarea id="configuration" class="form-control" rows="6" style="font-size: 0.8em;"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
                    <span><strong><i>Configuration Example:</i></strong></span>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 0px; padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 50px">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group has-success">
                            <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                <input type="search" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess1" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div><a class="all btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#">All</a></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(7, 94, 115, 0.3); padding-left: 0px;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                    <div id='question-list-container' style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
                    <div id='question-view-container' style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 15px; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(7,94,115,0.3);"></div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <!-- end of wrapper -->

    <!-- Begin footer -->
    <footer class="footer vertical-center">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="pull-right text-muted"><a href="#">Back to top</a>
            </p>
            <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Wei Song 2015.
                <a href="https://github.com/weixsong">https://github.com/weixsong</a> watkinsong@163.com.  Donate by Alipay: watkinsong@163.com</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script>
        (function(hijs) {
            //
            // hijs - JavaScript Syntax Highlighter
            //
            // Copyright (c) 2010 Alexis Sellier
            //

            // All elements which match this will be syntax highlighted.
            var selector = hijs || 'pre';

            var keywords = ('var function if else for while break switch case do new null in with void ' + 'continue delete return this true false throw catch typeof with instanceof').split(' '),
                special = ('eval window document undefined NaN Infinity parseInt parseFloat ' + 'encodeURI decodeURI encodeURIComponent decodeURIComponent').split(' ');

            // Syntax definition
            // The key becomes the class name of the <span>
            // around the matched block of code.
            var syntax = [
                ['comment', /(\/\*(?:[^*\n]|\*+[^\/*])*\*+\/)/g],
                ['comment', /(\/\/[^\n]*)/g],
                ['string', /("(?:(?!")[^\\\n]|\\.)*"|'(?:(?!')[^\\\n]|\\.)*')/g],
                ['regexp', /(\/.+\/[mgi]*)(?!\s*\w)/g],
                ['class', /\b([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\b/g],
                ['number', /\b([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\b/g],
                ['keyword', new(RegExp)('\\b(' + keywords.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g')],
                ['special', new(RegExp)('\\b(' + special.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g')]
            ];
            var nodes, table = {};

            if (/^[a-z]+$/.test(selector)) {
                nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
            } else if (/^\.[\w-]+$/.test(selector)) {
                nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(selector.slice(1));
            } else if (document.querySelectorAll) {
                nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            } else {
                nodes = [];
            }

            for (var i = 0, children; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                children = nodes[i].childNodes;

                for (var j = 0, str; j < children.length; j++) {
                    code = children[j];

                    if (code.length >= 0) { // It's a text node
                        // Don't highlight command-line snippets
                        if (!/^\$/.test(code.nodeValue.trim())) {
                            syntax.forEach(function(s) {
                                var k = s[0],
                                    v = s[1];
                                code.nodeValue = code.nodeValue.replace(v, function(_, m) {
                                    return '\u00ab' + encode(k) + '\u00b7' + encode(m) +
                                        '\u00b7' + encode(k) + '\u00bb';
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                nodes[i].innerHTML =
                    nodes[i].innerHTML.replace(/\u00ab(.+?)\u00b7(.+?)\u00b7\1\u00bb/g, function(_, name, value) {
                        value = value.replace(/\u00ab[^\u00b7]+\u00b7/g, '').replace(/\u00b7[^\u00bb]+\u00bb/g, '');
                        return '<span class="' + decode(name) + '">' + escape(decode(value)) + '</span>';
                    });
            }

            function escape(str) {
                return str.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
            }

            // Encode ASCII characters to, and from Braille
            function encode(str, encoded) {
                table[encoded = str.split('').map(function(s) {
                    if (s.charCodeAt(0) > 127) {
                        return s
                    }
                    return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + 0x2800);
                }).join('')] = str;
                return encoded;
            }

            function decode(str) {
                if (str in table) {
                    return table[str];
                } else {
                    return str.trim().split('').map(function(s) {
                        if (s.charCodeAt(0) - 0x2800 > 127) {
                            return s
                        }
                        return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - 0x2800);
                    }).join('');
                }
            }

        })(window.hijs);
    </script>
```

3rd edit:

I have this code

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
    $(this).trigger("enterKey");
}
```

});

I use xampp and when I press enter this is what happens. those "Empty list" are from the previous .json file but with a different id . I can't find that part

[image]

it has a lot of codes so i uploaded it here (edited: removed link. fixed now)

Comment: Is it possible to provide a fiddle or a plunk?

Comment: I'll try putting it in plunk

Comment: I think I found the solution for the existing link but I'll wait for the plunk now.

Comment: can I transfer the whole folder in plunk? you are referring to plnkr.co, right?

Comment: As long as its based on front end.

Comment: I'm trying to put it in github then import to plunk at the moment. what's your solution about it?

Comment: Please paste the html in your question and I'll try to explain.

Comment: I added html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the manual and missed and ingnored the node.js part. As you can see the index_builder.js uses fs, which I learned, that uses node.js. You have to use node.js and run index_builder.js. This will build an index.json file from your data.json(stored search results). The code uses the example source code I have to rebuild the index. Also, I am using xampp for local host.

```
Step 1. Download and Install node.js 
Step 2. Run Xampp Shell on elasticlunr project directory
Step 3. Type in node index_builder.js
Step 4. Elastic Search will work with the entered query
```

This is the code of my index_builder.js

```
var elasticlunr = require('./elasticlunr.js'),
fs = require('fs');

var idx = elasticlunr(function () {
this.setRef('page_id');

this.addField('title');
this.addField('tags');
this.addField('body');
this.addField('url');
});



fs.readFile('./example_data.json', function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;

var raw = JSON.parse(data);

var questions = raw.questions.map(function (q) {
return {
  page_id: q.page_id,
  title: q.title,
  body: q.body,
  url: q.url,
  tags: q.tags.join(' ')
  };
});

questions.forEach(function (question) {
idx.addDoc(question);
});

fs.writeFile('./example_index.json', JSON.stringify(idx), function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('done');
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `input` tag exists in between the `form` tag. This implies that upon pressing enter the form is submitted and therefore the page reloads thus removing any information you placed and showing the unadulterated results .

In the example provided by the developer, `$('input').bind('keyup', debounce(function () {` is used. Therefore, upon entering text the tags are searched. However, in your case, the control doesn't even shift to code that you are intending to run.

Please check this 
 https://jsfiddle.net/kaminasw/rqj68xt5/ where it should show alert upon pressing enter in the input.

```
$('input').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    alert();
});
```

Try to use the actual code with keyup event and compare the pressed key with enterKey code i.e. 13.

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    // 13 is ENTER
    if (e.which === 13)
    // Perform action
});
```

Comment: I use xampp for local. I see that the input is inside the form however, even with the input inside the form,  it works but it gives me empty result (see 3rd edit).

It's helpful tho. in the web host. it does what you just said. it reloads. thanks for that .

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.